# How to change the formatting of the output of Hibernate HQL query

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm developing a Spring Boot application with Spring Data JPA. I'm using a custom JPQL query to group by some field and get the count. Following is my repository method.

```
@Query("SELECT v.status.name, count(v) as cnt FROM Pet v GROUP BY v.status.name")
List<Object[]> countByStatus();
```

It's working and result is obtained as follows:

```
[
    [
        "pending",
        1
    ],
    [
        "available",
        4
    ]
]
```

However, I would like my Rest endpoint to respond with an output which is formatted like this

```
{
    "pending": 1,
    "available": 4
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You need to use projections to format the response. https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-projections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you want to produce a JSON where its properties ("pending", "available") are dynamic and come from the `SELECT v.status.name` part of the query.

Create a DTO to hold the row values:

```
package com.example.demo;

public class ResultDTO {

    private final String key;
    private final Long value;

    public ResultDTO(String key, Long value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public Long getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Change your query to create a new ResultDTO per row:

```
@Query("SELECT new com.example.demo.ResultDTO(v.status.name, count(v)) as cnt FROM Pet v GROUP BY v.status.name")
List<ResultDTO> countByStatus();
```

- "com.example.demo" is my package, you should change it to yours.

Then from your service class or from your controller you have to convert the `List<ResultDTO>` to a `Map<String, Long>` holding all rows' keys and values.

```
final List<ResultDTO> repositoryResults = yourRepository.countByStatus();
final Map<String, Long> results = repositoryResults.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(ResultDTO::getKey, ResultDTO::getValue));
```

Your controller should be able to transform `final Map<String, Long> results` to the desired JSON